# How can I disable CMake in some project folders of a VSCode workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, git-repo

I have a project that uses [git-repo](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/) so it contains multiple repos. The only way I can find of supporting this in VSCode is to use [multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) and add each repo as a separate folder within the workspace. Some of these repos use CMake but some don't. I find that when I open the workspace I get messages for these repos like:

> CMakeLists.txt was not found in the root of the folder 'MyFolder'

then VSCode attempts to setup CMake by creating a Build directory containing a bunch of default files.
I also get:

> CMake Tools would like to configure IntelliSense for the 'MyFolder' folder.

Is there any way to tell CMake to ignore a folder, maybe a setting in the .code-workspace file?

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/1069) (still open as of this comment) may be related. For those who said yes to _allow CMake to configure IntelliSense_ and want to undo it, just remove the `configurationProvider` key in `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`.

Comment: did not work for me

Answer (score 5):

I guess you installed Cmake Tools extension in VScode, it will automatically run when a folder is opened.
To avoid run cmake on specific folder, you can try create `.vscode/settings.json` on your folder. And set `"cmake.configureOnOpen": false`

Comment: I have set this setting to be false but I still get the pop-up with CMakeLists.txt selection, any recommendation?

Comment: Who's upvoting this? This is CMake Tools issue [#2338](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/2338). There is currently no setting to get rid of the warning.

Comment: this setting doesn't exist

Comment: didn't work for me too

Answer (score 1):

If you're on CMake Tools 1.13.40+, try using [the `cmake.sourceDirectory` setting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#cmake-settings) and specify an array of the CMake source directories you want to configure with CMake Tools.

You may also be interested in

- the `cmake.ignoreCMakeListsMissing` setting
- the `cmake.configureOnOpen` and `cmake.configureOnEdit` settings
- issue ticket [CMake Tools try to configure IntelliSense for Non-CMake projects #2338](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/2338)

Answer (score 0):

Do not install "CMake Tools", install only "CMake".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).